# Convert C# BitCount method used in image hashing to T-SQL involving Bitwise operators

Tags: t-sql, bitwise-operators

I am trying to convert the following `BitCount` method to `T-SQL`, but I have no idea how to even start.

For example, how could one manually instantiate a `varbinary` variable, similar to the `bitCounts` array below. BTW, the original code is located [on github](https://github.com/jforshee/ImageHashing/blob/master/ImageHashing/ImageHashing.cs). Any help in converting this method to `T-SQL` will be extremely helpful.

A few inputs, and corresponding outputs of this function are:

1. input=34762711265992831; output=23
2. input=1130323790528512; output=6
3. input=33900573146222676; output=17
4. input=31648412230258808; output=18
5. input=31877043259982883; output=11
6. input=0; output=0

```
private static byte[] bitCounts = {
    0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,5,6,6,7,6,7,7,8 
};

/// <summary>
/// Utility function for similarity.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="num">The hash we are counting.</param>
/// <returns>The total bit count.</returns>
private static uint BitCount(ulong num)
{
    uint count = 0;
    for (; num > 0; num >>= 8)
        count += bitCounts[(num & 0xff)];
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1630934-bit-counting

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.bit_count (@num AS BIGINT)RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @msb INT
    SET @msb = 0

    IF @num < 0
    BEGIN -- BIGINT is signed so treat the MSB differently
            SET @msb = 1
            SET @num = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF & @num
    END

    SET @num = @num - ((@num / 2) & 0x5555555555555555)
    SET @num = (@num & 0x3333333333333333) + ((@num / 4) & 0x3333333333333333)
    SET @num = (@num + @num / 0x10) & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F
    SET @num = @num + @num / 0x100
    SET @num = @num + @num / 0x10000
    SET @num = @num + @num / 0x100000000

    RETURN (@num & 0x3F) + @msb
END
```